# How to reference "this" in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate several input fields. The code below works fine, except for the focus method. I expect that it can not interpret the "input" variable which relates to the input location on the form. Question: How do I reference the location of the specific input, bearing in mind that there are 20+ inputs ? tks !

```
function validateInput(quantity,input)
{
     if (quantity.value !== " ") {
        if(isNaN(quantity)) {                                        
            $(".myerror_alert").append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Warning!</strong> You have entered an non valid character, go back and enter a real number </div>');
            input.focus();  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

 $(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity',function (){

     var quantity = $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".edit_quantity").val();
     var input = $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('quantity').filter(".edit_quantity");


    validateInput(quantity, input);

// MORE CODE GOES HERE //

});
```

HTML:

```
             <tr class='delete_row'>
                    <td><input class="product_id form-control" readonly="readonly" name="product_id[0]" type="text" value="123"></td>
                    <td><input class="edit_product_id form-control" readonly="readonly" name="product_id[0]" type="text" value="Euroshake Blackstone"></td>
                    <td><input class="edit_quantity" name="product_id[0]" type="text" value="120"></td>
                    <td id="price"><input class="unit_price form-control" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:right;" name="price" type="text" value="120.00"></td>
                    <td><input class="line_cost form-control" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:right;" name="cost" type="text" value="14400.00"></td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="padding-left:12px;"><input name="delete" type="checkbox" value="123"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML aswell?

Comment: You don't show where you call `validateInput` so we don't know what you are passing as the parameters. It should work if `input` is a jquery object

Comment: have you tried `$(input).focus()`? Also, sow us your html where you call `validateInput`

Comment: `find('quantity')` <- this probably doesn't find anything unless you are using a quantity tag, even then, I'm not sure if jQuery finds non-standard tags like that.

Comment: @dan08 it recognizes any xml tag, but it could be a typo easily

Comment: @LinkinTED added html as requested.  I am trying to validate the quantity field

Comment: @Vince — You still haven't shown how you call `validateInput`. You declare it, but you never call it.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ing your variables. They are not being found by your jquery logic. This just takes some troubleshooting on your end to make sure you find the elements you want to check.

Comment: This condition is so strange: `if(isNaN(quantity))`. By the name it suposed be a number but it seems that you *do not* want a number there. Anyway, if `if (quantity.value !== " ")` is true, `quantity` would never be a number.

Comment: @Quentin sorry, I omitted it in error. It is now been edited in.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, Sorry, I'm new to javascript. I want to test if the input is empty or is not a number, ie a semi colon etc.

Comment: @Vince sure, np, so you should use `isNaN` in the `value` property: `if (quantity.value !== " " && isNaN(quantity.value))`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  Thanks .. ok will do, I'll change it. However, how do I get focus to work on the input which triggered the BS alert ?

Comment: You should pay attention on what @dan08 said. The problem is probably there.

Comment: Is this what you need ? https://jsfiddle.net/jcv1d9ds/ If yes I will post an answer explaining it.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yes ! Exactly !  Perfect ! I added an extra row to your fiddle to test that the focus was selecting the  row with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was supose that in this part `.find('quantity')` you was probably meaning `.find('input')` as its previous statement, then I figure out that you were working with the same element there. So being the same element, you don't need to hold it's reference(in `input` var) and it's value(`quantity` var) to pass into `validateInput`. As this is a function, why not work with less code and make the function handles it, right? So I've changed it to pass only the element reference and inside the function with this condition `if ($input.val().length > 0 && isNaN($input.val()))` I could check if element ins't empty and also if it isn't a number:

```
function validateInput(input)
{
    var $input = $(input);

    if ($input.val().length > 0 && isNaN($input.val())) {   
        $(".myerror_alert").append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Warning!</strong> You have entered an non valid character, go back and enter a real number </div>');
        input.focus(); 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity',function (){
    validateInput(this);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jcv1d9ds/)

One important mistake you've done that you've workaround it - probably - without noticing it, is that you navigate through the element tree to find the input, but when you do `$(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity'` you're in fact binding an event in all elements with class `edit_quantity` inside the element with class `product_table`, so inside the event, your `this` **already is** the input, you don't need to go after it, as I did:

```
validateInput(this);
```

I hope this helps.